# How get docker container stats from manually

Tags: docker

I just want to know that how docker getting the following statistics from **/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/containerID, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/docker/containerID**

```
['cpu_stats']['cpu_usage']['total_usage']
['precpu_stats']['cpu_usage']['total_usage']
['cpu_stats']['system_cpu_usage']
['precpu_stats']['system_cpu_usage']
['memory_stats']['usage']
['memory_stats']['stats']['cache']
['memory_stats']['limit']
```

If somebody help, that will be very helpful for me

Comment: Have a look at this article: https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-collect-docker-metrics/

Comment: These are just overview, but what exact this behind, that need to know

Comment: Moby and Docker are both open-source. If you need to understand exactly how `docker stats` works, you'll want to review the source code there.